# Passing Entity object value in to nested CollectionTypes in a Symfony4 form

Tags: forms, e-commerce, symfony4, many-to-one

**Overview**: Foreach `VariantGroup` in a `Products` `VariantSets` I need to  create a dropdown containg that `VariantGroups` `Variants` in the Symfony form

**Details**:
I have a `Product` entity which is associated as a `ManyToMany` relationship to multiple `VariantSet` objects. The `VariantSet`objects contain multiple `VariantGroup` objects which need to generate a dropdown each to display their `Variant` choices.

For the nested `CollectionTypes` I need to only make accessible the options related to the parent `CollectionType`.

So the only `Variants` available should be related to the `VariantGroups` which are only the ones related to the available `VariantSets` which are associated to the initially parsed `Product`.

There is some info out there that points toward using the query builder to grab the relevant items only but I'm wondering if this is best practice. Also - how do I pass the previous forms (so getting the top level `Product` in the nested `CollectionType` for `VariantGroup` as `VariantSets` sits between these two).

Is this even possible to achieve using best practices in Symfony forms?

Example of the desired output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4tfi.png)

Comment: I'm heading down the avenue of using multiple nested `CollectionTypes` that end in a `EntityType` for the drop down.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote but feedback why this is a bad question, or what is needed that would help others answer this query, would really help out in creating a more specific and suitable question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. The answer was nested `CollectionType` forms and a custom query builder in the final form (for some reason it was calling all of the `Variant` objects in the DB, rather than using the ones associated to the parsed `VariantGroup` object:

**Main product form**

```
class ComplexProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        // Render the variant sets based on the parsed product
        $builder
            ->add('variantSets', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => VariantSetComplexProductType::class,
                'label'=> false,
                'by_reference' => true,


            ] );
        ;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            "data_class" => Product::class,
        ));
    }

}
```

**Render the products Variant Sets:** *(to get the correct `VariantGroups` associated to the main products `VarianSet` objects)*

```
class VariantSetComplexProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        // Render the groups based on the Variant sets
        $builder
            ->add( 'label' )
            ->add( 'variantGroups', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => VariantGroupComplexProductType::class,
                'label'=> false,
                'by_reference' => true
            ] )
        ;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults( [
            'data_class' => VariantSet::class,
        ] )
        ;
    }
}
```

**Render the Variant Sets `VariantGroups` with its `Variants` in a dropdown:**

The drop down of `Variant` objects needs to be done in a `FromEvent` using the `query_builder` options, as otherwise I had an issue where all the `Variant` objects were being called in the DB.

There need to be a check to make sure only the correct `Variant` objects were called based on the parsed `VariantGroup`.

```
class VariantGroupComplexProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        // Render the drop downs based on the Parsed variant group
        $builder
            ->add( 'label' )
            // Rendering of the drop down must be done after the previous form data is available
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, [$this, 'preSetData']);
        ;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults( [
            'data_class' => VariantGroup::class,
        ] );
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        /** @var VariantGroup $child */
        $child = $event->getData();


        $form
            ->add('variants', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Variant::class,
                'by_reference' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ( $child ) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.variant_group = :variant_group')
                        ->setParameter('variant_group', $child )
                        ->orderBy('u.label', 'DESC');
                },
'choice_label' => 'label',
            ));

    }
}
```